# File with ~ in name not found

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I have been trying to execute the basic usage program given here: https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python?

There is a error below saying No such file or directory, but I have opened the folder and there is goforward.raw file

```
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(157): fwdflat: min_ef_width = 4, max_sf_win = 25
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(429): TOTAL fwdtree 0.00 CPU -nan xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(432): TOTAL fwdtree 0.00 wall -nan xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(176): TOTAL fwdflat 0.00 CPU -nan xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(179): TOTAL fwdflat 0.00 wall -nan xRT
INFO: ngram_search.c(303): TOTAL bestpath 0.00 CPU -nan xRT
INFO: ngram_search.c(306): TOTAL bestpath 0.00 wall -nan xRT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "voice.py", line 221, in <module>
    stream = open(path.join(DATADIR, 'goforward.raw'), 'r+b')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/sphinx-source/pocketsphinx/test/data/goforward.raw'
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(429): TOTAL fwdtree 0.00 CPU -nan xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(432): TOTAL fwdtree 0.00 wall -nan xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(176): TOTAL fwdflat 0.00 CPU -nan xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(179): TOTAL fwdflat 0.00 wall -nan xRT
INFO: ngram_search.c(303): TOTAL bestpath 0.00 CPU -nan xRT
INFO: ngram_search.c(306): TOTAL bestpath 0.00 wall -nan xRT
```

Answer (score 0):

`~` symbol is only expanded to your home folder when you type the command in bash. Python does not expand `~` to your home folder.

If you want to specify a file name, specify a full absolute path, for example

```
DATADIR = "/home/rahullab/sphinx-source/pocketsphinx/test/data"
```

or specify a relative path.